# How to copy data from a user to another user by insert data if not exist and update if exist?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to copy the data that belong user A to user B. Firstly, i will get the user A's data.

```
$item = item::where('id_user', $user_a)->get();   
// id_user is FK inside item table
```

And then use the code below to create/update the existing record in user B to user A.

```
$test = item::createOrUpdate($item->toArray());
```

For example.

```
Item
id | id_user | id_item
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    1         3
4    2         1
```

As shown above, id_user 1 consist of 3 item while id_user 2 only 1 item. i want to copy id_item 2 and 3 to id_user 2 from id_user 1.

I want to copy all data from user A to user B, if the item exist it will just update else will insert new record for the user B. Is my way correct? I tried but it doesn't show any error but do not create or update for user B.

Comment: I think you should use `first()` instead of `get()` when you retrieve single record of the user. Then your code will work.

Comment: is that many-to-many relationship? if it is, you can just have a function that describes the relationship and you can attach to B those are attached to A.

Comment: @SagarGautam It's not single record.

Comment: @Wreigh any related example for that?

Comment: @SagarGautam See my answer, comment for clarifications.

Comment: @Zidance see my answer, I tagged the wrong person, sorry.

Comment: @Zidance Any way, it's okay

Comment: @SagarGautam Nothing happen although everything work but record not inserted or updated.

Comment: @Zidance are you using transaction ?

Comment: @SagarGautam no

Comment: For mass update, you need to define column names in `$fillable` property. have you added that ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes, i think i found what's wrong in my code. Thanks.

Comment: @Zidance Have you solved your problem ?

Comment: @SagarGautam forgot about using looping to createorupdate the data.

Comment: @Zidance really  ha ha :D

Answer (score 0):

In line with my comment.

Because I'm seeing a pivot table, it seems to be a many-to-many relationship.

A User belongsToMany Items and an Item belongsToMany Users.

Given that, you may put relationship functions on each Model like.

In User Model:

```
public function items() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

In Product Model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$userA = User::find($id_a);
$a_items = $userA->items; // this will return items that belong to user A.
```

You can now attach the items to another user:

```
$userB = User::find($id_b);
$userB->items()->attach($a_items); // if this doesn't work try, $a_items->pluck('id');
```

Note: State explicitly to Laravel your foreign key names if you didn't follow the naming convention. E.g., you used `id_user` as foreign key for `User`, while Laravel is expecting it to be `user_id`.

For info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Edit:

Since you already gave me the inputs, you can do this in your relationship methods, e.g., in User:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'user_product', 'id_user', 'id_product');
```

Comment: Sorry, what if i put id_user as primary key in my item table? E.g. i have 3 table, there is product, user, and user_product(item). in my user_product i put id_user as primary key and id_product as FK and primary key. If i am using your method i will get null value.

Comment: If you use my method, make sure to explicitly tell Laravel that you're using different convention for the keys. As I stated above, you are using `id_user`, but Laravel expects `user_id` instead. I will update my answer.

Comment: Not sure how it works. Nothing changes after operation successful. Nevermind, i will figure other ways by myself.